# How do I link xbbg to B-Pipe (Bloomberg)

Tags: python, bloomberg, blpapi

I'm currently using xbbg with no issues, but the Bloomberg API limits my personal license to 500k api hits per day. I'm getting B-Pipe access soon which should alleviate the limit but I'm unsure how to make sure xbbg calls from B-Pipe and not my desktop API.

Tried digging through the xbbg source but couldn't find a place to insert the B-pipe details. Has anyone gone down this road before?